# Ajax server side setup and teardown

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following situation:

Server-side, I have a relational database, and am doing some rather computationally-intensive requests on it.  For a request, there is a resource intensive setup task.  Many of my requests require this same setup step, which I don't want to repeat, which leads me to want a single call.  However, each request takes a lot of time, which makes me want to issue them asynchronously as several calls, so that the user gets stuff as it becomes available.  I could try to just "keep the setup step around", but I don't really want the server to try to guess when the client is done, and it can't rely on the client to tell it when to clean up.

Here's what I would LIKE to happen:
- Client-side, I gather up the requests that I want to make, A,B and C.  They all require the same setup step.
- So that I don't have to repeat the setup step, I issue one ajax call for A,B and C simultaneously.
- So that the user doesn't have to wait forever for results, I return answers for A,B and C asynchronously, handing them back to the client as the results become available.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/?A=1&B=2&C=3",
    partialSuccess: function (data) {
        if (partialSuccess.which == "A") {
            doStuffForTaskA();
        }
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("all tasks complete!");
    }
});
```

I'm pretty sure the sort of thing I have in the code above is not possible.  Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  (I am also the author of the server-side code.  It happens to be c sharp, but I'm somewhat more interested in this as a 'which protocol, and how does it work' question)

Comment: Do you want to run three requests in parallel? Or should there only be one request?

Comment: Have you considered setting up multiple ajax calls and composing the promises returned from the jquery ajax function?

Comment: you need 3 separate ajax requests, and wait for the responses from each. You can't get separate async responses from a single call unfortunately. You can also use jquery $.when to collect all the responses and do something when they all finish, if required. Or perhaps you could re-architect it entirely using WebSockets for a more 2-way communication channel

Comment: read the jQuery [Deffereds](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) article for information on the api

Comment: Could make initial request.. store status, data etc in session and use long poll requests to get updates